# Unable to drag and drop telerik components on windows forms

Tags: winforms, telerik, telerik-grid, rad-controls

I am trying to drag and drop Telerik RadGridView on my windows form. But instead of showing on the form(in designer view), it shows the control just below the designer i.e. the area where some of the controls like DataSet, Binding Source, FileDialog controls are shown when added to the form from the toolbox.

The same problem happens for any rad control like RadButton, RadLabel etc. I can work on the control by using the controls added to the form, but the problem is that in case of some controls like RadGridView, the smart tag is not available that makes a lot of things easier.

I think I am missing something, so that I am unable to drag-drop the controls. Can any one help me out?

Comment: I've got this with Infragistics 2013.2.  I've moved the references to my DLLs to a 3rd Party folder so I could do cloud builds.  I've tried drag/drop and it happens the same as you described.  I've even added my own Toolbox Tab with a reference to the controls in it - again Drag/Drop still puts them in the Component area below the form.  Did you get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by missing design time assembly in your GAC. Uninstall the all telerik controls from your computer, reinstall them and then update your project references. This should solve the problem.

More info [at this link](http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/winforms/general/radcontrols-for-winforms-are-not-loaded-at-design-time.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Can also be caused by a version mismatch. I had the latest version installed but code base referenced previous version (specifically 2011 Q2).

An uninstall of latest and install of 20011.Q2 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

you must ReInstall your telerik product then open your project and reload your toolbox.

this sometime happen like you update your visual studio or you install a new package of telerik.